# Programming animations for mathematical formulas

Tags: programming, animation, latex

I'm trying to make animations to explain mathematical concepts in which formulas would play a big role. I'd need text and formulas to do some simple things like fading in and out, moving, rotating, morphing, etc.

As my background is in programming, I figured Iid try to make some sort of automated process:

1. Generate SVG formulas out of LaTeX sources.
2. Animate the text/formulas.
3. Export as a video.

I've already managed to do step 1 with little trouble. Now, I know I could do step 2 with some animation software, but I've been looking for some solution that involves programming instead of WYSIWYG, because I feel more comfortable in that territory. I'm open to any language/library, although it's much preferable if it can run on UNIX-like systems. I've already checked some libraries like Cairo and such, but all seem to have big trouble using vector graphics instead of bitmaps, and although using SVGs is not a requirement for me, I think it'd make the process more simple.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend trying the [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) notebooks environment with one of several plotting libraries that support animation.

This combination lets you combine, on a single notebook page, text formatted with markdown, formulae with latex or mathjax, plots & graphs, etc. nice example [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/empet/Math/blob/master/DomainColoring.ipynb).

Amongst the plotting tools that support animation there are:

- [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) has [animations](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html#animation-examples-index) and even has an example of [saving to .mp4](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/basic_example_writer_sgskip.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-basic-example-writer-sgskip-py)
- [plotly](https://plot.ly/) supports [animations](https://plot.ly/python/animations/)
- [holoviews](http://holoviews.org/) has some animation demonstrations in their [showcase](http://holoviews.org/Tutorials/Showcase.html)
- [bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) has some interesting features but animation looks to be complex
- [bqplot](https://github.com/bloomberg/bqplot) is well worth a look
- the [VPython](http://vpython.org/) kernel can produce fantastic animations

It is well worth having a browse at https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/A-gallery-of-interesting-Jupyter-Notebooks#data-visualization-and-plotting to see some of the possibilities.

I would also suggest taking a look at [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/) which can produce an animation of any code that produces a plot as an image or a numpy image array it brings a lot of this together [here](https://zulko.github.io/blog/2014/11/29/data-animations-with-python-and-moviepy/) with the following being some examples of such animations:

[image]
[image]
[image]